# What changes should I do for the output to display with two decimal places?

Tags: python

I want my output to have a 2 decimal places result. What should I do?
Ideal output is:

Enter the number of plants to purchase: 14

Enter the price per unit of plant: 250.00

The total payable amount is: P3,350.00

```
 n1 = input('Enter number of plants: ')
 n2= input('Enter price per unit: ')
    
 mul= float(n1) * float(n2)
 mul2= (float(n1)-float(10)) * (float(n2))
 mul3 = float(10) * float(n2)
    
 discount2 = float (mul2)* float(0.15)
    
 total2=mul2-discount2
 total3= total2+mul3
    
    
    
 if float(n1)<=float(10):
     mul= float(n1) * float(n2)
     print('The total payable amount is: ', mul)
     
    
    
 elif float(n1)>float(10):
     print('The total payable amount is: ', total3)
```

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html for currency.

Comment: I am still new to python and I was also instructed to only use python

Comment: Your code is right this is format problem.. i edit your code chack new

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `str.format` function and I made some small adjustments to your code.

```
n1 = float(input('Enter number of plants: '))
n2 = float(input('Enter price per unit: '))

mul = n1 * n2

if n1<=10:
    print('The total payable amount is:  ${:0,.2f}'.format(mul))
else:
    print('The total payable amount is:  ${:0,.2f}'.format(0.85*mul+1.5*n2))
```

Answer (score 0):

A few answers missed the fact you also needed thousands separated by a comma. here is the `format` command which displays the price the way you expect it

```
n1 = input('Enter number of plants: ')
n2= input('Enter price per unit: ')

mul= float(n1) * float(n2)
mul2= (float(n1)-float(10)) * (float(n2))
mul3 = float(10) * float(n2)

discount2 = float (mul2)* float(0.15)

total2=mul2-discount2
total3= total2+mul3



if float(n1)<=float(10):
    mul= float(n1) * float(n2)
    print('The total payable amount is: ${:0,.2f}'.format(mul))
    
    
    
elif float(n1)>float(10):
    print('The total payable amount is: ${:0,.2f}'.format(total3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [formatted string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting). Also, convert the values to floats at the start, then there is no need to keep converting everything.

```
plants_str = input('Enter number of plants: ')
price_str = input('Enter price per unit: ')
plants = float(plants_str)
price = float(price_str)
total = plants * price
if plants > 10:
    total -= 0.15 * (plants - 10) * price
print(f"The total payable amount is: {total:0,.2f}")
```

But as noted in a comment, for serious applications involving currency you should use the decimal library. This ensures decimal numbers are represented exactly.

```
from decimal import Decimal
plants_str = input('Enter number of plants: ')
price_str = input('Enter price per unit: ')
plants = Decimal(plants_str)
price = Decimal(price_str)
total = plants * price
if plants > 10:
    total -= Decimal("0.15") * (plants - 10) * price
print(f"The total payable amount is: {total:0,.2f}")
```